# How to save captured photo in application directory in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I want to save captured photo in application directory where `SQLite` etc reside. I don't want to make any folder and any hidden file in the SD Card. How this can be save the captured photo in application directory.

I am trying this below but it is saving in the SD card that is hidden file but I don't want this approach.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String capturedPhotoName = "." + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        capturedPhotoName);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_INTENT_REQUEST);
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method to save captured image in application storage

```
 public Uri setImageUri() {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File file = new File(directory,System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }
```

Image will store at this location

```
/data/data/com.your.packagename/app_data/imageDir
```

Comment: What is the maximum size of `cacheDir` of the application ?, saving multiple files of large size wont create any issue ?

Comment: there is no fix size declared in documentation its depends on device internal storage

Comment: oh If device internal storage is 16 GB then it's cache size is what ?

Comment: Document says If you'd like to cache some data, rather than store it persistently, you should use getCacheDir() to open a File that represents the internal directory where your application should save temporary cache files.

When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete these cache files to recover space. However, you should not rely on the system to clean up these files for you. You should always maintain the cache files yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space consumed, such as 1MB. When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Comment: so it saying to save stuff which has around 1 MB size but here one captured photo size would be more then 2 MB then how to do it ?

Comment: OK but where it saves this any location ?

Comment: Glad to know it is working and thanks for appreciation

Answer (score 0):

get URI from onActivityResult() and convert it into bytes store bytes in Database.

```
byte[] UserPic = null;
UserPic = Base64.decode(result.getData(), 0);
```

save userPic in DataBase