# How to fetch image path file to one Activity to other Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout

I have an App that verifies the ID card by clicking photos from both sides, after clicking the picture front-side of the id card the user moves to another activity for clicking the picture back-side of the id card after completing those prosses the user redirect to another activity that the user sees both sides of the document into different ImageView but I don't know how to fetch or pass
those images on this Activity that user can see their ID card for confirmation.

**Here is my front side-scan activity**

```
    public class Front_Scan extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;

    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 101;

    public String currentPhotoPath;

    Button frontImgCap;
    Button frontImgCapAgain;
    Button frontNext;

    ImageView frontImg;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_scan);
        frontImg = findViewById(R.id.Image_id_front);
        frontImgCap = findViewById(R.id.imgCapture_front);
        frontImgCap.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        frontImgCapAgain = findViewById(R.id.Front_imgCapture_again);
        frontImgCapAgain.setVisibility(GONE);
        frontNext = findViewById(R.id.front_next);
        frontNext.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
                , new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                            File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
                            frontImgCapAgain.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            frontImgCap.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                            frontNext.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            frontImg.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
                        }
                    }
                });

        frontImgCap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //if system os is >= marshmallow, request runtime permission

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        //permission not enable, request it
                        String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        //show popup to request permissions
                        requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                    } else {
                        //permission already given
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                } else {
                    //system os < marshmallow
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();

                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void next(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Front_Scan.this, back_scan.class);
        Front_Scan.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }

    public void scanAgain(View view) {
        clearMyFiles();
        onCreateLayouts();
        frontImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.id_front));
    }

    void clearMyFiles() {
        File imgFile = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        if (imgFile != null) {
            imgFile.delete();
        }
    }

    public void onCreateLayouts() {
        frontImgCap.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        frontImgCapAgain.setVisibility(GONE);

        frontNext.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;

        }

    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "FRONT_ID_JPEG" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.nyabaapplication.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                activityResultLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Front Scan XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp"
    tools:context=".Front_Scan">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Scan Front Side"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background"
        app:cardCornerRadius="22dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Image_id_front"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/id_front" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/Front_imgCapture_again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/flag_transparent"
        android:text="Scan Again"
        android:onClick="scanAgain"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Position your document inside the frame. Make sure that all the data is clearly visible."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/imgCapture_front"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_ylo"
        android:text="Scan Now"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/front_next"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_ylo"
        android:text="Next Step"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="next"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is Back side-scan activity**

```
 public class back_scan extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher1;

    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 101;

    public String currentPhotoPath1;

    Button backImgCap;

    Button backImgCapAgain;

    Button backNext;

    ImageView backImg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_back_scan);

        backImg = findViewById(R.id.Image_id_back);

        backImgCap = findViewById(R.id.imgCapture_back);
        backImgCap.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        backImgCapAgain = findViewById(R.id.Back_imgCapture_again);
        backImgCapAgain.setVisibility(GONE);

        backNext = findViewById(R.id.back_next);
        backNext.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

        activityResultLauncher1 = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
                , new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                            File f1 = new File(currentPhotoPath1);
                            backImgCapAgain.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            backImgCap.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                            backNext.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            backImg.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f1));
                        }
                    }
                });

        backImgCap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //if system os is >= marshmallow, request runtime permission

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        //permission not enable, request it
                        String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        //show popup to request permissions
                        requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                    } else {
                        //permission already given
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent1();
                    }
                } else {
                    //system os < marshmallow
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent1();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void next1(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(back_scan.this, scanned_copy.class);
        back_scan.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }

    public void scanAgainBack(View view) {
        clearMyFiles1();
        onCreateLayouts1();
        backImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.id_back));
    }

    void clearMyFiles1() {
        File imgFile1 = new File(currentPhotoPath1);
        if (imgFile1 != null) {
            imgFile1.delete();
        }
    }

    public void onCreateLayouts1() {
        backImgCap.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        backImgCapAgain.setVisibility(GONE);

        backNext.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent1();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile1() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "BACK_ID_JPEG_" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath1 = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent1() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile1();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.nyabaapplication.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                activityResultLauncher1.launch(takePictureIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Back Scan XML file is almost same as front side XML**

**Here is the activity that shows both sides of the ID Card together**

```
    public class scanned_copy extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button finishBtn;

    ImageView scanIDBack;

    ImageView scanIDFront;

    String storeFrontScan;
    String storeBackScan="BACK_ID_JPEG.jpg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanned_copy);

        readFrontImgFromFile();
        readBackImgFromFile();

        scanIDBack = findViewById(R.id.Scan_id_back);

        scanIDFront = findViewById(R.id.Scan_id_front);

        finishBtn = findViewById(R.id.ScanfinishBtn);
        finishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(scanned_copy.this, WellDone.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    public void readFrontImgFromFile()
    {
        File imgFileFront = new  File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+storeFrontScan);
        if(imgFileFront.exists())
        {
            scanIDFront.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFileFront));

        }
    }

    public void readBackImgFromFile()
    {
        File imgFileBack = new  File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+storeBackScan);
        if(imgFileBack.exists())
        {
            scanIDBack.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFileBack));

        }
    }


}
```

**The XML File of this Activity**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".scanned_copy">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Scanned ID Card"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:progress="85"
            android:progressTint="@color/yellow" />


        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_gray"
            app:cardCornerRadius="22dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Have a final check if all data is clearly visible and that it matches the information you have entered in previous steps."
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Front Side"
                    android:textSize="26dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>


                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_gray"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="22dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/Scan_id_front"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/id_front" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                  <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Back Side"
                    android:textSize="26dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>


                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_gray"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="22dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/Scan_id_back"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/id_back" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/ScanfinishBtn"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style_ylo"
            android:text="Finish Verification"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: How about saving those images in cache then you just need to pass the url. And after user confirmation step, I think you need to send those images to server right? Just save it in cache then come and get it later. Remember to clear it when everything's done.

Comment: actual I'm new in this field can you place clarify how to save those images in cache and pass through the Url and how to implement this

Comment: I will not provide code sample here, but you can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606202/how-to-save-captured-photo-in-application-directory-in-android for saving image and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir() for access cache dir. Then you will have uri like /data/data/com.your.packagename/app_data/imageDir... then you pass it into other activity using intent or whatever you want. In new activity, you access to the above uri and get images. Then display it to your view.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700 (seven hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have the path to the files that were saved. Pass them through to the last activity as intent extras.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity